Prices for events that require participant approval
We have an event that requires approval. Applicants can apply for either a smaller cheaper thing or a larger more expensive one. We need to know at the time of application which size the applicant wants, and they need to pay the corresponding amount after being approved.
I'm having two possibly related issues:

If "Require participant approval?" is checked, the user doesn't see the price on the application page.  They only see the price after they are approved and are in the process of confirming their registration. This issue was identified and theoretically corrected here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15240 But there is a note here from Eileen that "This PR never went into 4.5" so maybe the fix has never been merged in?

On the admin side, we can select the price as part of the approval, but that choice doesn't carry forward to the confirmation. It doesn't even default to the price you selected during approval, the user has complete freedom to select the lower price.


I'm wondering if there is a setting that controls this or if anyone has any other guidance for me. Would using price sets change anything? Thank you for any assistance!
I am on CiviCRM CiviCRM 5.73.1 on Drupal 7.91 (will be upgrading shortly to 7.100).

Just noting (since i had to learn this) that per https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/online-event-registration several Participant Status need to be enabled for this 'approval' option to even show in the settings
